# How to remove consecutive instances of new line \n with ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a bunch of text in ruby that looks like this:

```
 "\n \n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote Recipe - NYT Coking\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote\n \n \n \n \nBy Sarah DiGregorio\n \n \n \n \n Yield\n About 3 ½ cups\n \n \n Time\n 6 hours and 10 minutes\n \n \n \n \n \n EmailShare on PinterestShare on FacebokShare on Twiter\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n Linda Xiao for The New York Times. Fod Stylist: Judy Kim.\n \n \n \n \n"
```

What I would like to do to this string is replace consecutive `\n` new line characters with only one `\n` . In other words, if there is more than one newline character `\n`, then I want to only keep on of the newline characters, removing the consecutive ones.

This regex *almost* does the trick: `full_text.gsub(/((\n \n)\2*)/, '')` -- but you will see that in some consecutive groups of `\n` the `gsub` removes them entirely when I want it to only leave one `\n`.

Ideally I want to pass regex to `gsub` such that the output is:

```
" \n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote Recipe - NYT Coking   \n   Slow-Coker Tomato Compote  \nBy Sarah DiGregorio  \n Yield\n About 3 ½ cups \n Time\n 6 hours and 10 minutes \n   EmailShare on PinterestShare on FacebokShare on Twiter   \n   Linda Xiao for The New York Times. Fod Stylist: Judy Kim.  \n"
```

What regext do I need to write so that `gsub` leaves only one `\n` where there are consecutive instances of `\n`?

Comment: Try `full_text.gsub(/\n[ \n]+/, "\n")` or ```full_text.gsub(/(\R)[ \r\n]+/, '\1')```

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your comment -- I tried your suggestion, it the output is not what I am looking for. It removes all the `\n` characters. The regex needs to replace the consecutive `\n` with only one `\n`

Comment: I edited my question so that it's more clear.

Comment: I updated my first comment suggestions. I kept `''` as replacement since I copied/pasted the code from your question.

Comment: I am confused. There are no consecutive `\n`s in your string. Can you describe *exactly* what you want to replace with what?

Comment: @JörgWMittag when I say, consecutive line break characters (`\n`), I am referring to a line break character,`\n`, which follows another line break character. In my example above there are groups of `\n` that stand next to each other. These groups of `\n` that stand next to each other are separated by other nonline break characters. In short, any part of the string that contains at least two line break characters, immediately next to each other (`"\n \n"`), is what I mean by "consecutive `\n`s". I want to replace groups of consecutive `"\n"` in my string with only one line break character: "\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
full_text = full_text.gsub(/(\R)(?:\s*\R)+/, '\1')
```

*Details*:

- `(\R)` - Group 1 (the group value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): any line break sequence
- `(?:\s*\R)+` - one or more occurrences of zero or more whitespace chars and any line break sequence.

As the replacement is `\1`, Group 1 value, the first line break sequence is put back into the resulting string where it was in the original string.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/UPQACE):

```rb
full_text = "\n \n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote Recipe - NYT Coking\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote\n \n \n \n \nBy Sarah DiGregorio\n \n \n \n \n Yield\n About 3 ½ cups\n \n \n Time\n 6 hours and 10 minutes\n \n \n \n \n \n EmailShare on PinterestShare on FacebokShare on Twiter\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n Linda Xiao for The New York Times. Fod Stylist: Judy Kim.\n \n \n \n \n"
p full_text.gsub(/(\R)(?:\s*\R)+/, '\1')
# => "\n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote Recipe - NYT Coking\n Slow-Coker Tomato Compote\nBy Sarah DiGregorio\n Yield\n About 3 ½ cups\n Time\n 6 hours and 10 minutes\n EmailShare on PinterestShare on FacebokShare on Twiter\n Linda Xiao for The New York Times. Fod Stylist: Judy Kim.\n"
```

Comment: thank you Wiktor! I will accept this as the correct answer once SO lets me.